# Possibly the object is 'null'

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting the following Typescript errors in my code
I'm getting these parameters from a previous screen. As in the example of the react nativigation documentation.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

```
interface PixChargeAmountProps {
  route?: string;
}

const Amount: React.FC<PixChargeAmountProps> = ({ route }) => {
const { trackOriginFlow } = route.params;
}
```

**console.log(route) ->**

```
"params": {"trackOriginFlow": "ACTIVITIES_SCREEN_BUTTON"}, "path": undefined}
```

I get the following errors from **route.params**

route = Possibly the object is 'null'

params = Property 'params' does not exist in type 'string'

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Please post the context (3 lines above and below) the `"params": {"trackOrigi...` line.

Comment: Estou seguindo esse exemplo do react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to use `route` as `const { trackOriginFlow } = route.params;` and are saying that it cannot be `null`, then your interface definition is incorrect.

It's probably more something along the lines of:

```
interface PixChargeAmountProps {
  route: {
    params: {
      trackOriginFlow: string
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'd recommend reading the typescript guide, instead of trying to assemble this type yourself.
See: [Type checking with TypeScript](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/)